# Silverlight MessageBox.Show() not displaying Chinese characters

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, localization, character

I am localizing my application and through it there are messageboxes to alert the user of certain things. When I include chinese characters in text areas they look like a bunch of squares when debugging in VS2010 but then are converted to the proper characters when displayed in the UI through objects bound to properties. But when the code directly calls messagebox.show("chinese characters") it ends up just displaying a bunch of empty squares. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "double bytes" in Silverlight.  All strings are encoded in utf-16.  Double bytes is a hack from the days of 8-bit code pages to find a way to encode CJK text.  You will have to convert such encoded text to utf-16 with the Encoding class.

Seeing text displayed as squares can be because the characters are control codes due to a bad encoding.  Or missing support for the glyphs in the fonts installed on the machine.  That's a rapidly disappearing problem too, you'd normally only have it on XP without East Asian font support installed.

Comment: Well the characters originated from the translators and were provided in an Excel spreadsheet, they are supposedly Unicode. From the spreadsheet I import the data into a table where the columns are nvarchar. If I load the data into my program, assign it to a property, and bind it to a textblock on the screen it displays as Chinese. If I instead use the string to initiate a MessageBox.Show(ChineseCharacterString) it displays a bunch of boxes instead. What part of the process would you guess is going wrong?

Comment: Ugh.  No idea, chase the bytes, not the strings.

Comment: Speaking as a veteran of those days, it wasn't really a hack, just a lot of distinct multibyte encodings, as opposed to the smaller set of multibyte encodings we have today (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32). Now, when a particular language couldn't get its act together enough to agree on fewer than a dozen separate encodings...